# Problem accessing REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint where I can do (CRUD) operations in the browser on a particular folder. I am trying to get all the folders using C# code

```
// Test code
                try
                {
                    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
                    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", GetSecureString("password"));
                    Web sites = context.Web;
                    context.Load(sites, website => website.Folders);
                    Folder folders = sites.RootFolder;
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(folders.Folders.Count);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

I got an exception

> "Access denied. You are not authorized to perform this action or access this resource.".

Can anyone help me out how to solve the issue?

Comment: I fail to see the accessing of REST.  Does the user whose credentials you are providing have access to the library and folder?  Is this a SharePoint app? You have it tagged, but at the same time, you state you are accessing a REST resource when you are not, so I want to clarify that.  If you are in an app, verify that the app has appropriate permissions.

Comment: Sorry if this seems too basic but just to get it out of the way: Did you attempt whatever action you're doing in a normal browser, as the user you're plugging in, to make sure permissions are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have read permissions on the site. If you already have them, then try to assign yourself "colaborate" permissions.